# Flask not redirecting correctly?

Tags: python, flask

So I get input from my html with this code and then redirect it to an other function.

```
@app.route('/', methods = ['POST'])
def search():
    rsn = request.form['username']
    return redirect(url_for('username', rsn=rsn))
```

It redirects to the following function:

```
@app.route('/username=<rsn>', methods = ['GET', 'POST'])
def username(rsn):
    ...
```

I expected the url to be the one that app.route says... so if rsn = Hey the url would be

```
/username=Hey
```

But for some reason the url turns into

```
/username%3DHey
```

Why?

Comment: Because that's the proper encoding of a `=` character in the URL path. Your browser and Flask handle the URL correctly still.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`=` is a [*reserved character* in URLs](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-2.2), and Flask is correctly [URL percent encoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding#Percent-encoding_reserved_characters) the character to `%3D`. It is a reserved character because it carries special meaning in [path parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6765627/url-path-parameter-use-cases) and [query strings](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_string).

Your browser and Flask will still handle the character correctly.

Note that Flask does not support routes with path parameters (key-value pairs after a path element, delimited by a `;` colon), where a `=` would be a valid delimiter character; instead you generally use the path elements as parameters directly. If you really wanted to you could write a [custom converter](http://werkzeug.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/routing/#custom-converters) to capture `(;key(=value)?)*` patterns.

Comment: might not really relate... but why doesnt '/' get encoded to '%2F'?

Comment: @Bonjouri: Because Flask uses it specifically as a path delimiter, its intended purpose.

Answer (score 0):

`%3D` is the percent-encoded code for `=`. Flask encodes the equals sign as that is standard convention. Browsers still interpret this correctly.